# Geometric proof for the half angle tangent

Tags: trigonometry

Using the fact that the angle bisector of the below triangle splits the opposite side in the same proportion as the adjacents sides, I need to give a geometric proof of the half-angle tangent $$  \tan  \frac{\beta}{2} \ \  = \ \ \frac{\sin \beta}{1 \ + \ \cos \beta} \ \ .  $$

[image]

This is what I've done so far:

I tried to write the sides $ \ a \ $ and  $ \ c \ $ in terms of $ \ b_1 \ $ and $ \ b_2 \ $ using the Pythagoras Theorem and the relations of sine and cosine. After a lot of manipulation, I ended up with $$ \tan \frac{\beta}{2} \ \  =  \ \ \frac{\sin \beta \ · \ b_2^2 · \ \cos \beta}{b_1 \ + \ b_2} \ \ . $$ But this is certainly wrong.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any fraction can as per a rule of fractions be algebraically also written to form an identity taking sum/difference of numerator and denominator separately with or without a common multiplier. Using this rule

$$ \frac{p}{q}=\frac{r}{s}=\frac{ap+br}{aq+bs}$$
$$
\tan \beta/2=\frac{b_1}{a}=\frac{b_2}{c}=\frac{b_1+b_2}{a+c}=\frac{b}{a+c}=\frac{b/c}{a/c+1}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta+1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\frac{b_1}{a}=\frac{b_2}{c}$ then
$$\frac{b_1}{a}=\frac{b_2}{c}=\frac{b_1+b_2}{a+c}$$

Comment: Can you please explain this identity? I'm not following the steps.

Comment: @MiltonLeal Denote by $x:= \frac{b_1}{a}=\frac{b_2}{c}$ Then $$b_1=ax \\b_2=cx$$ Now calculate $\frac{b_1+b_2}{a+c}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dfrac{b_1}{a}=\dfrac{b_2}{c}$ and $b_1+b_2=b$, we have
$$
\tan(\beta/2)=\frac{b_1}{a}=\frac{b}{a+c}=\frac{(b/c)}{(a/c)+1}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\beta+1}.
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why b1/a = b/a+c ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more purely geometric proof.
Join a rectangle with sides $b$ and $c$ to the side $b$ of the triangle as shown in the figure below, and show that the bisector of angle $\beta$ passes through the upper right vertex of this rectangle.
(You can use the fact that $b_1/a = b_2/c,$ but there is also a proof involving alternating angles and an isosceles triangle.)

[image]

Now, using the fact that $b = c \sin\beta$ and $a = c\cos\beta,$
you can easily derive the desired formula for $\tan(\beta/2).$
If you set $c = 1$ (which you can do without loss of generality),
then you can read the formula off directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to show the identity by a **proof without words**.

[image: Proof with words]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If we take the large triangle in the original diagram to be a *right* triangle, then from the marked triangles, we have $ \ \tan \frac{\beta}{2} \ = \ \frac {b_1}{a} \ \ , \ \ \cos \frac{\beta}{2} \ = \ \frac {a}{H} \ \ , \ \ \sin \frac{\beta}{2} \ = \ \frac {b_1}{H} \ \ , \ \ \cos \beta \ \ = \ \ \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ , \ \ \sin \beta \ \ = \ \ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ . $

Applying the law of sines to the upper triangle of the two into which the large right triangle is subdivided, we may write
$$ \frac{\sin \frac{\beta}{2}}{b \ - \ b_1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sin (90º - \beta)}{H} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sin (90º + \frac{\beta}{2})}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\sin \frac{\beta}{2}}{b \ - \ b_1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\cos   \beta }{H} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\cos  \frac{\beta}{2} }{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \tan \frac{\beta}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sin \frac{\beta}{2}}{\cos  \frac{\beta}{2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{b \ - \ b_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ = \ \ \sin \beta \ - \ \frac{b_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ = \ \ \sin \beta \ - \ \frac{b_1}{H}·\frac{H}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ . $$
[this also demonstrates in passing the proportion from the angle-bisector theorem]

The law-of-sines equation also gives us $ \ \frac{\cos   \beta }{\cos  \frac{\beta}{2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{H}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ \ , \ $ hence
$$ \tan \frac{\beta}{2} \ \ = \ \  \sin \beta \ - \ \sin \frac{\beta}{2} \ · \ \frac{\cos   \beta }{\cos  \frac{\beta}{2}} \ \ = \ \ \sin \beta \ - \ \tan \frac{\beta}{2}  ·   \cos   \beta  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \tan \frac{\beta}{2} \ · \ ( \ 1 \ + \ \cos   \beta \ ) \ \ = \ \  \sin \beta   \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \tan \frac{\beta}{2}  \ \ = \ \  \frac{\sin \beta}{1 \ + \ \cos   \beta} \ \ . $$