# Geometric proof of half tangent of sum of angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I can show algebraically that $\tan(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})=\frac{\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)}$. Is there however a way to show it geometrically?
I found [Geometric proof for the half angle tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764737/geometric-proof-for-the-half-angle-tangent) and https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-geometrical-proof-of-the-formula-tan-A-B-tanA-tanB-1-tanAtanB but I cannot come up with a proof for the above relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it via this figure.
The circle is a unit circle.
(I have omitted the labeling of segments of length $1,$ $\sin\alpha,$ $\cos\alpha,$ etc., but it may be helpful to supply those labels in various places.)

[image]

Comment: Why is that angle $(\alpha+\beta)/2$? Are you using some properties for circles?

Comment: The intercepted angle theorem is a relatively easy way to get it (you might want to reflect the $\beta$ angle across the $y$ axis to see this). You can also do some angle-chasing via the thin isosceles triangle in the middle of the figure.

Comment: What a wonderful proof without words!